# Fourier coefficients of $L^{\infty}$ function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Ive been looking for bounds on Fourier coefficients on bounded measurable functions but can only find for bounded variation. Is there nothing to say about the coefficients of the former? and why if that is the case?

It certainly looks like they are bounded on finite measure spaces

$\int_{[0,1]}fe^{-xn}d\lambda<\mid\mid f\mid \mid$

What about the converse, given bounded sequence is there an $L^{\infty}$ function?

Comment: Riemann-Lebesgue shows they converge to zero and Parseval shows that they are square summable (with sum of abs value of squares bounded by $||f||^2$); nothing more can be said as there are continuos (hence bounded) functions with Fourier coefficients for which $\sum |c_n|^{2-\epsilon} = \infty$ for all $\epsilon >0$

Comment: @Conrad if square sum is bounded by norm of $ f$ which is boundes by lebegue measure of the unit intervall times bound for $ f $shouldt that number bound all coefficents?

Comment: yes but that is a weak hypothesis - the fact that $\sum |c_n|^2=||f|^2$ is a much stronger one

Comment: @conrad sorry by weak you refer to "asking for more" i.e less number of functions satisfy it? What I am saying is $\sum \hat{f} \le ||f||^2 \le leb([0,1]) \cdot sup f \le M$ implies $\hat{f}(n) \le M$ for all  $n$

Comment: We already know that $\hat{f}(n) \to 0, n \to \infty$ for example, so $|\hat{f}(n)| \le \epsilon, n \ge n(\epsilon)$; similarly it is true that $|\hat{f}(1)|^2+..\hat{f}(k)|^2 \le M$ for any $k$ - these conditions are generally much stronger than a simple pointwise bound

Comment: @conrad so we know about bounds but not speed of decay when we dont have regularity?

Comment: yes - essentially we need bounded variation (or better like various degrees of smoothness etc) to say anything about the rate of decay; there are continuos functions for which the Fourier series converges uniformly on $[0, 2\pi]$ but the coefficents are about $\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)(\log^a n)}, a >1, n>1$ so we barely get square summability

Comment: @Conrad now I think I understand what you said before, are you saying that the bound I obtained via my estimate is much larger then the one you provide in the 5th comment? is that what you mean by weaker?

Comment: yes - weaker means larger in this context as the point of upper bounds generally is to make them small

Comment: @Conrad Could you please elaborate on your comment on the newly linked post?

Comment: @stoic which question? Would be happy to take a look

Comment: @Conrad Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4791531/why-do-there-exist-continuous-functions-with-sum-n-c-n2-epsilon-infty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bound on Fourier Coefficients on $L^\infty$ functions

In order to get bound on Fourier coefficients on any $L^p$ function, we first must see how is Fourier transform making sense on that $L^p $ space and what is the image of that $L^p $ space under the Fourier transform.

So the entire story of Fourier transform starts from $L^1$ and we have that image of $L^1$ under Fourier transform is contained in $L^\infty$ ( by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma it's actually contained inside $C_0$, in fact image of $L^1$ forms a dense sub-algebra of $C_0$) and moreover, $$||\hat{f}||_{L^\infty} \le ||f||_{L^1}$$ i.e. Fourier transform is a bounded Linear transformation from $L^1 \to L^\infty$ with operator norm $\le 1$. In case of $L^2$, we have Plancherel hence, Fourier transform is a Unitary operator on $L^2$. Then you note by Hausdorff-Young inequality, that Fourier transform is actually a bounded linear transformation from $L^p \to L^{q}$ where ( $1 \le p \le 2$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ ) with operator norm $\le 1$ ( by Riesz-Thorin interpolation ) .

But what happens when $p > 2$ ? If we have something like a Hausdorff-Young inequality in this case, then we should move forward, right? As that should give us some bound etc. **But Alas! no such inequality exists!** In fact , the first question that should bother us is where does the Fourier transform takes this $L^p $ spaces?

Recall that for $L^p,p>2$, the Fourier transform is defined basically in terms of tempered distributions. So let's compute the Fourier transform of an $L^\infty$ function by hand, say $f \equiv 1$. As $f \in L^1_{loc}(\Bbb R)$ we have the tempered distribution $T_f$ defined by $T_f(\phi)=\int_{\Bbb R} f \phi ,\forall \phi \in \mathscr{S}(\Bbb R)$ where $\mathscr{S}(\Bbb R)$ is the space of all Schwarz class functions on $\Bbb R$. As $f \equiv 1$, we get that the Fourier transform $$\hat{T_f}(\phi)=T_f(\hat{\phi})=\int_{\Bbb R} \hat{\phi}(x)dx=\phi(0)=\delta_0(\phi), \forall \phi \in \mathscr{S}(\Bbb R)$$
Then as you note, the fourier transform of the $L^\infty$ function  $f \equiv 1$ is the dirac measure at 0, i.e. the Fourier transform is not even a function! So you shouldn't be expecting any bound for Fourier coefficients on $L^\infty$ functions, isn't it?

> On finite measure spaces

Then there is definitely a bound, and it's trivially true, since $L^p \subset L^1, \forall p$, so basically you're working with the initial bound on $L^1$