# Does there exist a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-|y|}f(x-y)dy=e^{-|x|}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, convolution

What I did so far is letting $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$ then by taking the fourier transform of the given equation I get $\widehat{g*f}(x)=\widehat{g}(x)\widehat{f}(x)=\widehat{g}(x)$ which leads to $\widehat{f}=1$

Does this lead to something ?

Comment: The Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is bounded, but sadly the transform is not onto. 
 The inverse Fourier transform of a nonzero constant function is not in $L^1$ and in fact is not even a function.

Comment: so this means there is no such function $f$ because its fourier transform is constant ?

Comment: You can use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to see that if $f \in L^1$, then $\hat f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.  This proves what @UmbertoP. says.

Comment: That is correct. If you are curious you can look up the Fourier transform of the "delta function" which is in fact not a function.

Comment: To see Umberto's ideas more clearly you also may visit https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768553/fourier-coefficients-of-l-infty-function/3775866#3775866 . Here you'll also find some explicit computation